# Let $\langle a \rangle $ be a cyclic group of order $n$ and let $m$ and $n$ be relatively prime. Show that $f(x) = x^m$ is an automorphism.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I'm stuck on this proof. I need to prove:

Let $\langle a \rangle $ be a cyclic group of order $n$ and let $m$ and $n$ be relatively prime. Show that  $f(x) = x^m$ is an automorphism.

And this is the work progress I have made so far:

We need to show 3 things:

1. $f$ is injective from $\langle a \rangle$ to $\langle a \rangle$
2. $f$ is surjective from $\langle a \rangle$ to $\langle a \rangle$
3. For all $x,y \in \langle a \rangle$, $f(xy) = f(x)f(y)$

Part 3 is trivial, $f(xy) = (xy)^m = x^my^m=f(x)f(y)$

Since $\langle a \rangle$ is finite, 1 and 2 are logically equivalent. My approach is to show that $f$ is surjective. For this, let $p \in \langle a \rangle$ be given, and let $k = \textrm{ord}(p)$. Then $k|n$.

If $\textrm{ord}(p)=k$ and $k|n$ then $p^n = e$.

I'm really not sure where to go next with the proof. If I can show that there is $x$ such that $p = x^m$ I will be done.

Answer (score 1):

$\rm\langle a^m\rangle = \langle a \rangle,\:$ by $\rm\, a^m$ has order $\rm\,n,\,$ by $\rm\ a^{mk}\!=1\!\iff\! n\mid mk\!\iff\! n\mid k,\: $ by $\rm\:(n,m)=1,\:$ and Euclid.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**  $mk+nl=1$ for some $k,l$ integeres.

What is $f(a^l)=$?

**P.S.** It is probably easier to prove that $\ker(f)=\{ e \}$. That is because if $x \in \ker(f)$ then $x^m=e$ and you already know that $x^n=e$...

Answer (score 0):

You have already shown the homomorphism property holds.

To show that $f$ is 1-1, let $a^i, a^j \in \langle a \rangle$ and $f(a^i)=f(a^j).$ Then $(a^i)^m=(a^j)^m \Rightarrow a^i=a^j$ since $m$ and $n$ are coprime $(i.e., (mi)\mod{n}=(mj)\mod{n}$)

Now, since $f$ is 1-1 and has the same set as its domain and codomain, it follows from set theory that $f$ is 1-1 if and only if $f$ is onto. This is a very useful result for verifying automorphisms.

Answer (score 0):

Choose $a^i\in(a)$ for some $i\in\mathbb Z.$

$(m,n)=1\implies\exists~x,y\in\mathbb Z$ such that $mx+ny=1$ i.e. $(xi)m=i-n(yi).$

Consequently $f(a^{xi})=a^{mxi}=a^{i-n(yi)}=a^i.$